# Pyomo/python code for ship-flow restriction in optimization

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, pyomo

I have some struggles on how to implement one restriction in my optimization problem.

[Mathematical expression of the restriction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irXo6.png)This is my first attempt on the shipflow-restriction. This works when T = 1. 
Whit T not 1, it generates errors. Need a more general approach to for coding the restriction.

```
def Flow_Of_Ships_rule(model, i, v, h):
    print(h)
    # max(h - model.TimeVisitingPort[k] - model.TimeTravelingPort2Port[k, i]) = 2 
    if h == 1:
        return sum(model.VesselTravel[i, j, v, h] for j in model.Node if j!=i) + model.VesselWait[i, v, 8]\
    - sum(model.VesselTravel[k, i, v, (8 - model.TimeTravelingPort2Port[k, i])] for k in model.Node if k!=i) - model.VesselWait[i, v, 7] == 0
    elif h == 2:
        return sum(model.VesselTravel[i, j, v, h] for j in model.Node if j!=i) + model.VesselWait[i, v, h - model.TimeVisitingPort[i]]\
    - sum(model.VesselTravel[k, i, v, (9 - model.TimeTravelingPort2Port[k, i])] for k in model.Node if k!=i) - model.VesselWait[i, v, 8] == 0 
    else:
        return sum(model.VesselTravel[i, j, v, h] for j in model.Node if j!=i) + model.VesselWait[i, v, h - model.TimeVisitingPort[i]]\
    - sum(model.VesselTravel[k, i, v, (h - model.TimeVisitingPort[k] - model.TimeTravelingPort2Port[k, i])] for k in model.Node if k!=i) - model.VesselWait[i, v, h - model.TimeVisitingPort[i] - 1] == 0

model.Flow_Of_Ships = Constraint(model.Node, model.Vessel, model.Time, rule=Flow_Of_Ships_rule)

###############################################################################
def One_Flow_Of_Ships_rule(model, v, h):
    return sum(sum(model.VesselTravel[i, j, v, h] for j in model.Node) for i in model.Node) + sum(model.VesselWait[i, v, h] for i in model.Node) <= 1 

model.One_Flow_Of_Ships = Constraint(model.Vessel, model.Time, rule=One_Flow_Of_Ships_rule)

###############################################################################
def No_Travel_rule(model, i, j, v, h):
    if i != j:
        return Constraint.Skip
    else: 
        return model.VesselTravel[i, j, v, h] == 0

model.No_Travel = Constraint(model.Node, model.Node, model.Vessel, model.Time, rule=No_Travel_rule)
```

Comment: it looks like your question would benefit from some use of code formatting features in StackOverflow

Comment: Also, after reformatting the question a bit, it would be nice to see the error message. Have you tried reducing the problem until the error doesn't occur anymore?